# Immutable Object3D properties in ThreeJS r68

Tags: javascript, three.js

The [migration notes for r67 to r68](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration#r67--r68) state:

> `Object3D`'s `position`, `rotation`, `quaternion` and `scale` properties are now immutable.

What does this mean in practice? I'd like some more details about this. I couldn't find an issue or pull request for details.

For example, how would the following code snippets need to change?

```
obj.position.x = 10;
```

Also, how is this immutability enforced? Is there a moment in time when the object is frozen, or are the `Vector3` etc instances immutable once constructed?

Answer (score 4):

After some experimentation, it seems that the the properties are readonly, and they access mutable objects.

So this is valid:

```
obj.position.x = 10;
```

But this will be ignored:

```
obj.position = new THREE.Vector3(10, 0, 0);
```

Unfortunately this does not cause any observable error or warning — it just silently doesn't do what you ask it to.

The following would work:

```
obj.position.set(10, 0, 0);
```

To find violations of this new restriction, try searching for the following strings (you may like to use a regex to make the whitespace optional):

- `.position =`
- `.rotation =`
- `.quaternion =`
- `.scale =`